# C++ syntax error and missing type specifier

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

Visual C++ 2008 gives me this weird error, so I stripped out all of the excess stuff in my header file (util.h
), and it boils down to this:

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

void pause();

#endif
```

When I try to compile the above code I get this:

```
Compiling...
util.cpp
util.h(4) : error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'
util.h(4) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
<snip>
```

I am deeply confused. Even if I comment out the ifndef, define, and endif, preprocessor directives, It still says the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours of looking, I finally figured it out!

The error is not in the header file itself. Header files are copied and pasted into source files, where they are included. So I looked where I included the file, and I saw in util.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"b
#include "util.h"
<snip>
```

That extra `'b'` is causing the error. C++ thinks it is a variable, but doesn't see a type specifier, so it assumes `'b'` is a new integer. Then it thinks I should terminate its declaration with a `';'` to precede `'void'`. The entire issue is just a stupid extra character, and a not very helpful error message.

Comment: No thats the thing. The line pointed to by the error was completely fine.

Comment: That line `#include "stdafx.h"b` should have produced a specific diagnostic about extra tokens on the `#include` directive. (gcc does this.) A careful reading of the C++ standard indicates that a `#include` directive line that doesn't match one of the two forms (`#include <...>` or `#include "..."`) causes undefined behavior, but it's a very easy error for the compiler to diagnose.